# Integrating CLIPS with Qt

Tags: c++, user-interface, clips

I've been trying to build a GUI with Qt. However, I have no idea how to integrate CLIPS with the signals and slots of Qt.

For example, in the GUI if a user presses `ctrl+r` it should run the source file entered. Similarly, the agenda has a different window which updates as the rules are loaded. How can I integrate all of this with Qt?

I'm also open to any ideas you may have about building a frontend for CLIPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CLIPSShell on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsshell/. It's written in Qt.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me. I've also looked at `clipsmm`. Do you have any idea on how to build that library on Ubuntu?

Comment: I think you use the autopen.sh provided to build it. https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/faq/autotools-faq.html

Comment: Or maybe just copying the folder into my directory would work? Thanks for all your help till now though